# How to convert Query to Schema

Tags: schema

I want to obtain record type info like:

```
List<RecordType> lstrecord = new List<RecordType>([Select id,Name from RecordType where sObjectType = 'Move__c' and Name = 'Draft' ]);
```

using schema

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Could you please take a bit of time to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) then [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/292119/edit) your question to clarify what you are asking and to explain what you already tried?

Comment: I need to convert List lstrecord = new List([Select id,Name from RecordType where sObjectType = 'Move__c' and Name = 'Draft' ]); into schema class

Answer (score 1):

For your specific object you can use:

```
Schema.RecordtypeInfo devRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Move__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Draft');
```

Comment: List<RecordType> lstrecordId = [Select Name, Id From RecordType where sObjectType='Move__c' and isActive=true LIMIT 1];

Comment: Can you explain what you mean please?

Comment: I want  To Get Sobject Record Type Id By Record Type Name Without Soql

Comment: Just see the code above. If you need the Id only you can write:
Id devRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Move__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Draft').getRecordTypeId();